# DLL Injector fails on some machines?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

First of all, no I'm not hacking a game, this is a simple IP redirector for a software.

I found a DLL injector thta can also call exports from the library, whichwas exactly what I needed.  In my machine it works great (Win 7 x64), however, in some machines, when it injects the program just says "Stopped working" or gets stuck. Why is that? Here's the code.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

using Syringe.Win32;


namespace Syringe
{
    public class Injector : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Internal class to represent an Injected Module within Injector's target process.
        /// Simply manages finding export addresses for functions, and caches these addresses for
        /// potential future use.
        /// </summary>
        private class InjectedModule
        {
            private Dictionary<string, IntPtr> exports;

            public ProcessModule Module { get; private set; }
            public IntPtr BaseAddress { get { return Module.BaseAddress; } }

            public InjectedModule(ProcessModule module)
            {
                Module = module;
                exports = new Dictionary<string, IntPtr>();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Get the address of a given function exported in the Module.
            /// If the function can't be found, this will throw <see cref="Win32Exception"/>
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="func">Name of function to search for</param>
            /// <returns><see cref="IntPtr"/> representing the address of this function in the target process</returns>
            /// <exception cref="Win32Exception">Thrown if unable to find function address in module</exception>
            public IntPtr this[string func]
            {
                get
                {
                    if (!exports.ContainsKey(func))
                        exports[func] = FindExport(func);
                    return exports[func];
                }
            }

            /**
             * Actual function to find export - loosely modelled off Cypher's idea/code for loading module into this
             * process to find address. Loads module as data, finds RVA of function and uses to find address in target 
             * process
             */
            private IntPtr FindExport(string func)
            {
                IntPtr hModule = IntPtr.Zero;
                try
                {
                    // Load module into local process address space
                    hModule = Imports.LoadLibraryEx(Module.FileName, IntPtr.Zero, LoadLibraryExFlags.DontResolveDllReferences);
                    if (hModule == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    // Call GetProcAddress to get the address of the function in the module locally
                    IntPtr pFunc = Imports.GetProcAddress(hModule, func);
                    if (pFunc == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    // Get RVA of export and add to base address of injected module
                    // hack at the moment to deal with x64
                    bool x64 = IntPtr.Size == 8;
                    IntPtr pExportAddr;
                    if (x64)
                        pExportAddr = new IntPtr(Module.BaseAddress.ToInt64() + (pFunc.ToInt64() - hModule.ToInt64()));
                    else
                        pExportAddr = new IntPtr(Module.BaseAddress.ToInt32() + (pFunc.ToInt32() - hModule.ToInt32()));

                    return pExportAddr;
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Imports.CloseHandle(hModule);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private Process _process;
        private IntPtr _handle;
        private Dictionary<string, InjectedModule> injectedModules;

        public Injector(Process process) : this(process, true) { }
        public Injector(Process process, bool ejectOnDispose)
        {
            if (process == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("process");
            if (process.Id == Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot create an injector for the current process");

            Process.EnterDebugMode();

            _handle = Imports.OpenProcess(
                ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation | ProcessAccessFlags.CreateThread |
                ProcessAccessFlags.VMOperation | ProcessAccessFlags.VMWrite |
                ProcessAccessFlags.VMRead, false, process.Id);

            if (_handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            _process = process;
            EjectOnDispose = ejectOnDispose;
            injectedModules = new Dictionary<string, InjectedModule>();
        }

        public bool EjectOnDispose { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Injects a library into this Injector's process. <paramref name="libPath"/> can be 
        /// relative or absolute; either way, the injected module will be referred to by module name only.
        /// I.e. "c:\some\directory\library.dll", "library.dll" and "..\library.dll" will all be referred to
        /// as "library.dll"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="libPath">Relative or absolute path to the dll to be injected</param>
        public void InjectLibrary(string libPath)
        {
            // (in?)sanity check, pretty sure this is never possible as the constructor will error - left over from how it previously was developed
            if (_process == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This injector has no associated process and thus cannot inject a library");
            if (_handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This injector does not have a valid handle to the associated process and thus cannot inject a library");

            if (!File.Exists(libPath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("Unable to find library {0} to inject into process {1}", libPath, _process.ProcessName), libPath);

            // convenience variables
            string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(libPath);
            string libName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);

            // declare resources that need to be freed in finally
            IntPtr pLibRemote = IntPtr.Zero; // pointer to allocated memory of lib path string
            IntPtr hThread = IntPtr.Zero; // handle to thread from CreateRemoteThread
            IntPtr pLibFullPathUnmanaged = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(fullPath); // unmanaged C-String pointer

            try
            {
                uint sizeUni = (uint)Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(fullPath);

                // Get Handle to Kernel32.dll and pointer to LoadLibraryW
                IntPtr hKernel32 = Imports.GetModuleHandle("Kernel32");
                if (hKernel32 == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                IntPtr hLoadLib = Imports.GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "LoadLibraryW");
                if (hLoadLib == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                // allocate memory to the local process for libFullPath
                pLibRemote = Imports.VirtualAllocEx(_handle, IntPtr.Zero, sizeUni, AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
                if (pLibRemote == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                // write libFullPath to pLibPath
                int bytesWritten;
                if (!Imports.WriteProcessMemory(_handle, pLibRemote, pLibFullPathUnmanaged, sizeUni, out bytesWritten) || bytesWritten != (int)sizeUni)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                // load dll via call to LoadLibrary using CreateRemoteThread
                hThread = Imports.CreateRemoteThread(_handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, hLoadLib, pLibRemote, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (hThread == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                if (Imports.WaitForSingleObject(hThread, (uint)ThreadWaitValue.Infinite) != (uint)ThreadWaitValue.Object0)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                // get address of loaded module - this doesn't work in x64, so just iterate module list to find injected module
                IntPtr hLibModule;// = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (!Imports.GetExitCodeThread(hThread, out hLibModule))
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                if (hLibModule == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Exception("Code executed properly, but unable to get an appropriate module handle, possible Win32Exception", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

                // iterate modules in target process to find our newly injected module
                ProcessModule modFound = null;
                foreach (ProcessModule mod in _process.Modules)
                {
                    if (mod.ModuleName == libName)
                    {
                        modFound = mod;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (modFound == null)
                    throw new Exception("Injected module could not be found within the target process!");

                injectedModules.Add(libName, new InjectedModule(modFound));
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pLibFullPathUnmanaged); // free unmanaged string
                Imports.CloseHandle(hThread); // close thread from CreateRemoteThread
                Imports.VirtualFreeEx(_process.Handle, pLibRemote, 0, AllocationType.Release); // Free memory allocated
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ejects a library that this Injector has previously injected into the target process. <paramref name="libName"/> is the name of the module to
        /// eject, as per the name stored in <see cref="Injector.InjectLibrary"/>. Passing the same value as passed to InjectLibrary should always work unless a 
        /// relative path was used and the program's working directory has changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="libName">The name of the module to eject</param>
        public void EjectLibrary(string libName)
        {
            string libSearchName = File.Exists(libName) ? Path.GetFileName(Path.GetFullPath(libName)) : libName;

            if (!injectedModules.ContainsKey(libSearchName))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("That module has not been injected into the process and thus cannot be ejected");

            // resources that need to be freed
            IntPtr hThread = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                // get handle to kernel32 and FreeLibrary
                IntPtr hKernel32 = Imports.GetModuleHandle("Kernel32");
                if (hKernel32 == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                IntPtr hFreeLib = Imports.GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "FreeLibrary");
                if (hFreeLib == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                hThread = Imports.CreateRemoteThread(_handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, hFreeLib, injectedModules[libSearchName].BaseAddress, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (hThread == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                if (Imports.WaitForSingleObject(hThread, (uint)ThreadWaitValue.Infinite) != (uint)ThreadWaitValue.Object0)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                // get exit code of FreeLibrary
                IntPtr pFreeLibRet;// = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (!Imports.GetExitCodeThread(hThread, out pFreeLibRet))
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                if (pFreeLibRet == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Exception("FreeLibrary failed in remote process");
            }
            finally
            {
                Imports.CloseHandle(hThread);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call an export with no parameter in the target process (i.e. SomeFunc( void );). This function will only
        /// return once the remote thread in the target process has returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="libName">Name of the injected module in which the function should be found</param>
        /// <param name="funcName">Name of the exported function to call</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="IntPtr"/> representing the return value of function <paramref name="funcName"/> in module <paramref name="libName"/></returns>
        public IntPtr CallExport(string libName, string funcName)
        {
            return CallExport((uint)ThreadWaitValue.Infinite, libName, funcName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call an export with no parameter in the target process (i.e. SomeFunc( void );). This function returns after
        /// <paramref name="timeout"/> ms have elapsed, or the remote function finishes (whichever comes first).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="timeout">Number of miliseconds to wait for the remote function to return</param>
        /// <param name="libName">Name of the injected module in which the function should be found</param>
        /// <param name="funcName">Name of the exported function to call</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="IntPtr"/> representing the return value of function <paramref name="funcName"/> in module <paramref name="libName"/></returns>
        public IntPtr CallExport(uint timeout, string libName, string funcName) // param location to avoid possible overload / generic confusion
        {
            return CallExportInternal(timeout, libName, funcName, IntPtr.Zero, null, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call an export with type <typeparamref name="T"/> data parameter. <typeparamref name="T"/> must be a struct (i.e. a 
        /// value type or user-defined struct). User-defined structs must have the <see cref="System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute"/> set to
        /// <see cref="System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential"/> or <see cref="System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit"/>. User-defined
        /// structs containing variable length C-style strings should adorn strings with <see cref="CustomMarshalAsAttribute"/> and set the value to the appropriate
        /// <see cref="CustomUnmanagedType"/> value.
        /// This function will wait until the remote function finishes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of data remote function expects. Value type or struct only.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="libName">Name of the injected module in which the function should be found</param>
        /// <param name="funcName">Name of the exported function to call</param>
        /// <param name="data">Data of type <typeparamref name="T"/> to be sent as argument to remote function</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="IntPtr"/> representing the return value of function <paramref name="funcName"/> in module <paramref name="libName"/></returns>
        public IntPtr CallExport<T>(string libName, string funcName, T data) where T : struct
        {
            return CallExport<T>((uint)ThreadWaitValue.Infinite, libName, funcName, data);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call an export with type <typeparamref name="T"/> data parameter. <typeparamref name="T"/> must be a struct (i.e. a 
        /// value type or user-defined struct). User-defined structs must have the <see cref="System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute"/> set to
        /// <see cref="System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential"/> or <see cref="System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit"/>. User-defined
        /// structs containing variable length C-style strings should adorn strings with <see cref="CustomMarshalAsAttribute"/> and set the value to the appropriate
        /// <see cref="CustomUnmanagedType"/> value.
        /// This function will wait for <paramref name="timeout"/> miliseconds or until the remote function finishes (whichever comes first).
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of data remote function expects. Value type or struct only.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="timeout">Number of miliseconds to wait for the remote function to return</param>
        /// <param name="libName">Name of the injected module in which the function should be found</param>
        /// <param name="funcName">Name of the exported function to call</param>
        /// <param name="data">Data of type <typeparamref name="T"/> to be sent as argument to remote function</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="IntPtr"/> representing the return value of function <paramref name="funcName"/> in module <paramref name="libName"/></returns>
        public IntPtr CallExport<T>(uint timeout, string libName, string funcName, T data) where T : struct
        {
            IntPtr pData = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                int dataSize = CustomMarshal.SizeOf(data);
                pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(dataSize);
                CustomMarshal.StructureToPtr(data, pData, true);
                return CallExportInternal(timeout, libName, funcName, pData, typeof(T), (uint)dataSize);
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pData);
            }
        }

        private IntPtr CallExportInternal(uint timeout, string libName, string funcName, IntPtr data, Type dataType, uint dataSize)
        {
            string libSearchName = File.Exists(libName) ? Path.GetFileName(Path.GetFullPath(libName)) : libName;

            if (!injectedModules.ContainsKey(libSearchName))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("That module has not been injected into the process and thus cannot be ejected");

            IntPtr pFunc = injectedModules[libSearchName][funcName];
            // resources that need to be cleaned
            IntPtr pDataRemote = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr hThread = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                // check if we have all required parameters to pass a data parameter
                // if we don't, assume we aren't passing any data
                if (!(data == IntPtr.Zero || dataSize == 0 || dataType == null))
                {
                    // allocate memory in remote process for parameter
                    pDataRemote = Imports.VirtualAllocEx(_handle, IntPtr.Zero, dataSize, AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
                    if (pDataRemote == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                    // rebase the data so that pointers point to valid memory locations for the target process
                    // this renders the unmanaged structure useless in this process - should be able to re-rebase back to
                    // this target process by calling CustomMarshal.RebaseUnmanagedStructure(data, data, dataType); but not tested
                    CustomMarshal.RebaseUnmanagedStructure(data, pDataRemote, dataType);

                    int bytesWritten;
                    if (!Imports.WriteProcessMemory(_handle, pDataRemote, data, dataSize, out bytesWritten))
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }

                hThread = Imports.CreateRemoteThread(_handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, pFunc, pDataRemote, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                if (hThread == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                uint singleObject = Imports.WaitForSingleObject(hThread, timeout);
                if (!(singleObject == (uint)ThreadWaitValue.Object0 || singleObject == (uint)ThreadWaitValue.Timeout))
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                IntPtr pRet;
                if (!Imports.GetExitCodeThread(hThread, out pRet))
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                return pRet;
            }
            finally
            {
                Imports.VirtualFreeEx(_process.Handle, pDataRemote, 0, AllocationType.Release);
                Imports.CloseHandle(hThread);
            }

        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (EjectOnDispose)
            {
                foreach (string key in injectedModules.Keys)
                {
                    EjectLibrary(key);
                }
            }
            if (_handle != IntPtr.Zero)


                Imports.CloseHandle(_handle);


   _handle = IntPtr.Zero;

            Process.LeaveDebugMode();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

NoW I suppose some of you won't read it all.. but I don't understand why it's failing on some machines. They're using win 7 x64, just like me. I inject like so:

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(Path + @"\MyProgram.exe", "Argument1"))
                        {
                            while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero && !process.HasExited)
                                Thread.Sleep(waitWindowSleep);

                            if (process.HasExited)
                                return;

                            for (int i = 0; i < maxTryCount; i++)
                            {
                                using (Injector injector = new Injector(process))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        injector.EjectOnDispose = false;
                                        injector.InjectLibrary(dll);
                                        if ("127.0.0.1" != IPAddress.Loopback.ToString())
                                            injector.CallExport<IPInfo>(dll, "SetIP", new IPInfo("127.0.0.1"));
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        Thread.Sleep(failInjectSleep);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

So why does it crash on some machines??  thanks.

**edit:** debuggining the program.. http://puu.sh/4Hvcf.png - error i'm getting. both process and app are ran as admin.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I can't as it doesn't happen o nmy machne..

Comment: There is more than 1 way to debug a program.  Having a log file that you log checkpoints to as well as any exceptions is a tried and true way of doing things when your code is executed in environments you don't have much control over.

Comment: very stupid question, but did you check in those machines that crashes if they`re x64 too?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio yes they are. main post updated with exception im getting.

Comment: It seems that the account that is running the program don't have enough privilegies. Try run the same problem as admin as see if it works.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I tried turning UAC off and on, turning comptability to win xp or running as admin (both process and app). Nothing! Is there any other dll injector that can call exports?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question, I felt the need to answer it.

The exception message you are receiving sums it up pretty good. 
What happens is the following: The library you are using needs to call OpenProcess and CreateRemoteThread of a different Process. The library needs to enable SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE and therefore calls "EnterDebugMode()", which sets the Application Privilege Constant SE_DEBUG_NAME. For this action to succeed, the user account must have Debug Rights (see below). Only Administrators (and the local machine) do have this right.

Solution: Run the Application as Administrator with the required rights. It might help to make sure that "requireAdministrator" is set in the manifest file of the application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.enterdebugmode(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787339(v=ws.10).aspx